# Relations not working in Laravel and MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-4

Hello iam working LAravel and MOngodb App:
I have Following Scenario:
    I have Comment and their hits collection like this:
Hoots Model Collection

```
 "_id": ObjectId("52ef89e9c6b93ca123f2fd37"),
 "user_id": "52df9ab5c6b93c8e2a8b4567",
 "hoot": "Hello Thius is Tewst",
 "updated_at": ISODate("2014-02-03T12:22:01.530Z"),
 "created_at": ISODate("2014-02-03T12:22:01.530Z")
```

and Its hits Model collecton like this:

```
 "_id": ObjectId("52ef8d5ec6b93c6d24f2fd37"),
 "created_at": ISODate("2014-02-03T12:36:46.130Z"),
 "dip": NumberInt(1),
 "hits": NumberInt(0),
 "post_id": "52ef89e9c6b93ca123f2fd37",
 "updated_at": ISODate("2014-02-03T13:35:20.766Z")
```

So here One comment i.e hoot have one collection describing their like and dislikes

i have a model anem Hoots

```
<?php

 use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;

 class Hoots extends Eloquent {

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
 protected $table = 'hoots';

 public $timestamps = true;

 protected $fillable = array('user_id', 'hoot');

  public function gethit()
 {
   return $this->hasOne('Hitdip');
 }
 }
```

And Hitdip model for their hits record

```
<?php
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;

class Hitdip extends Eloquent {

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
 protected $table = 'hitdip';

 public $timestamps = true;

 protected $fillable = array('post_id','hits', 'dip' ,'type');

  public function gethoot()
 {
   return $this->BelongsTo('Hoots');
 }
```

}

But When i am trying to get hoot and hit record related to them , i am getting an error

```
 Hoots::where('user_id',$user_id)->gethit;
```

Kindly review? 
Error

```
Undefined property: Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Builder::$gethit (View: /var/www/hututoo/app/views/profile/profile_connect/profile.blade.php) (View: /var/www/hututoo/app/views/profile/profile_connect/profile.blade.php)
```

Comment: And the error is ..? Or we should guess by ourselves?

Comment: @u_mulder sorry for half info. Review Question again I have updated error

Comment: `gethit` is property, `gethit()` is function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one- to one relationship things are simple. above relations are defined correctly. But we need to fetch things in this format

```
Hoots::with('gethit')->find(id)->get();
Hoots::with('gethit')->where('user_id',$user_id)->get();
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem but with one to many ... can't seem to figure it out ... please help

Comment: @Raiden Where is the problem?

Comment: Im using one to many relation and when I do something like 
`$subcategories = $categories->subcategories()->get()` where categories has many subcategories.  It gives me the `undefined method subcategories` error, and I do have the subcategories method in the categories model which has a `hasMany("SubcategoriesModel")` relation. And the SubcategoriesModel has a `belongsTo("CategoriesModel")` also

Comment: @Raiden Sorry for late reply But you can do this . Specify id here. hasMany("SubcategoriesModel",'category_id','id'); and then call like . Category::with('subcategories')->where('condition')->get();

Comment: Here how we can work with $lookup aggregation of mongodb .Is there any package please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Some time Class name does not treat as object so you will have to pass directly in the function.

You need to changed the gethit and gethoot function and you need to pass class object
example:

```
public function gethit(){
   return $this->hasOne(new gethit(),'Hoots','post_id','_id');
}
```

Same as for gethoot

```
public function gethoot(){
  return $this->BelongsTo(new Hoots()); 
}
```

In one- to many relationship like Hoots have many post. So you can call

```
$posts = Hoots::with('gethit')->where('user_id','52df9ab5c6b93c8e2a8b4567')->get();
```